# Change system tray icon using MVVM pattern (C# / WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm programming an application using C # (WPF) and MVVM pattern. The application allows for sending notifications between clients of a local network. The following design example describes what I've said before:

[image]

When the client application minimizes it places it in the system tray.

The notification system sending works fine.

My question is: when client 2 application is minimized and client 1 sends a notification: how can I change the system tray icon of client 2 to notify that a new notifications has been received (using MVVM pattern)?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

The code for create the notify try icon is:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using ControlPanelNetClient.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ControlPanelNetClient.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        readonly ViewModelControlPanel _vm;

        private NotifyIcon m_notifyIcon;
        private WindowState m_storedWindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _vm = new ViewModelControlPanel();
            base.DataContext = _vm;

            m_notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
            m_notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Click to open.";
            m_notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "KM Control Panel";
            m_notifyIcon.Text = "KM Control Panel";
            m_notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("favicon.ico");
            m_notifyIcon.Click += new EventHandler(NotifyIcon_Click);            

            this.Closed += new EventHandler(MainWindow_Closed);
            this.StateChanged += new EventHandler(MainWindow_StateChanged);
        }

        private void MainWindow_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckTrayIcon();
        }

        void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _vm.StopListeningThread();
            m_notifyIcon.Dispose();
            m_notifyIcon = null;
        }

        void MainWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Hide();
                if (m_notifyIcon != null)
                {
                    m_notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                m_storedWindowState = WindowState;
            }                
        }

        void MainWindow_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            CheckTrayIcon();
        }

        void NotifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Show();
            WindowState = m_storedWindowState;
        }

        void CheckTrayIcon()
        {
            ShowTrayIcon(!IsVisible);
        }

        void ShowTrayIcon(bool show)
        {
            if (m_notifyIcon != null)
            {
                m_notifyIcon.Visible = show;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the so far code you have tried? btw im not the downvoter :)

Comment: What kind of plugin do you use for using tray? Did you write your own? If so, show us.

Comment: You change NotifyIcon.Icon.  That means whoever constructs the NotifyIcon (probably in app.cs or mainwindow.cs) has to hold both a reference to it and to the tcp client (or its managing type) for client 2.  When a message comes, the tcp client notifies those interested of the new state of the application, and the one holding both updates accordingly.  This is called coding--the filling in of the parts that don't exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon. I don't think we have an easy solution if you want to change the icon by using MVVM.
For tray icon in WPF, you can check out this one http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon
Below is a sample code to create a tray icon using that library

```
   <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon"               
                        IconSource="{Binding IconPath}"
                        ToolTipText="{Binding Tooltip}"
                        ContextMenu="{StaticResource SysTrayMenu}"
                        DoubleClickCommand="{Binding ManageCommand}">
        </tb:TaskbarIcon>
```